# How do I drawtext superscript -1 (unicode)?

Tags: java, android, unicode, drawtext, superscript

Unfortunately, I need to directly drawText on a button and I have to put -1 superscript on it.

Problem is that drawText prints small square instead of '\u207b' or ⁻ while it correctly prints  '\u00b9' or ¹. I suspect drawText does not recognize certain unicode characters.

In this case, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess, but that character probably isn't supported by the font that you're using. Try looking for a font that supports it.

Comment: I'm looking for such a font for Android, so I can embed it into my app. Do you any?